# Water filter (expired)

Tags: lasting-effects-duration, expiration-dates, water-filter-purifier, contaminate, public-sanitation

In public places, including public library, free drinking water systems are normally provided for public. Not all water filter system has water filter indicator light to let everyone knows when the filter needs to be changed. I often drink from this water filter but just realized the weird taste of the water.

I'm concern if they never change the water filter and/or the filter has accumulated excessive contaminants. What is the short term and long term negative health effects drinking from expired water filter? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What country is this? Is the public water supply not safe to drink? Water from a public water supply in virtually all developed nations is perfectly safe to drink without filtration of any sort.

Comment: Australia. Water from the tap is safe to drink but the question is the water filter. Sorry for the misunderstanding.